# What is the complexity for Renaming a column in postgresql/redshift?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, ddl

It might be trivial for someone who has done the Rename column operation on Redshift before. Is it O(n) or O(1). Since I have got a 10 million+ rows on a production DB, just want to ensure that it's not going to be expensive or causing any downtime.
The column for which I want to run a rename contains Null values.
Also can the implementation be different for Redshift and postgres. AFAIK the postgres engine my redshift uses would be 9.2. Not really sure.

Comment: Redshift is **very** different to Postgres. Which one **are** you using?

Comment: In Postgres a rename is just an update to the catalog tables. It is completely independent on the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Executed the rename column query, it took less than a second on redshift with 10M+ rows. So it takes constant time. Thanks